# Change Border MinimumHeightRequest from StaticRecourse depending Light or Dark Theme

Tags: collectionview, maui

In a `CollectionView` i use a `Border` with `MinimumHeightRequest` , trying to change the Height with StaticRecource depending on Dark or Light Theme.
Works with change the Stroke color or the Border but not the Height. Is this the wrong way or am i missing something.

In App.xaml the Style.

```
 <Style x:Key="Nieuwslight" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="MinimumHeightRequest" Value="300" />
        </Style>
        
        <Style x:Key="NieuwsDark" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="MinimumHeightRequest" Value="220" />
        </Style>
```

And the CollectionView with the Border

```
 <CollectionView
        x:Name="lstBal"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource systemRed},
                                  Dark={StaticResource Donkerrood}}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
        SelectionChanged="lstBal_SelectionChanged"
        SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="20" Orientation="Vertical" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="NieuwsBorder"
                    MinimumHeightRequest="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Nieuwslight},
                                             Dark={StaticResource NieuwsDark}}"
                    Stroke="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightBorderColor},
                                             Dark={StaticResource Maroon}}"
                    StrokeShape=" RoundRectangle 10"
                    StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Grid Padding="15,0,0,0" ColumnDefinitions="*,2*">
                        <Frame
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            BorderColor="Transparent"
                            CornerRadius="15"
                            HeightRequest="150">
                            <Image
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                HeightRequest="150"
                                WidthRequest="120">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <UriImageSource
                                        CacheValidity="5"
                                        CachingEnabled="True"
                                        Uri="{Binding Foto}" />
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                        </Frame>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Padding="25,5,5,0"
                            FontSize="22"
                            Text="{Binding Fototekst}"
                              TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource DarkColor},
                                 Dark={StaticResource LightTextColor}}" />
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Comment: Found this that works , in App.xaml i added  a x:Key for the default and large MinimumHeightRequest . Then in Border   MinimumHeightRequest="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource defaultMinimumHeightRequest},
                                                 Dark={StaticResource largeMinimumHeightRequest}}"

Comment: In 2 days i put it as Answer then it is better to read the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it .

In App.xaml set the Height for Minimum or Large.

```
 <x:Double x:Key="defaultMinimumHeightRequest">220</x:Double>         
 <x:Double x:Key="largeMinimumHeightRequest">300</x:Double>
```

And in MainPage.xaml for the Border

```
 <Border x:Name="NieuwsBorder"
                    MinimumHeightRequest="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource defaultMinimumHeightRequest},
                    Dark={StaticResource largeMinimumHeightRequest}}"/>
```